HealthConnect: how to know is the connection is already activated
I followed these steps: here
But I don't know how to determinate if the connexion with HealthConnect is already operational or not. Do you have an idea please?

You can test your app's connection to Health Connect by using the Health Connect Toolbox app, which can be downloaded from here. That page also has a description on how to use the test app, to either submit test data into health connect to see if your app can read it, or read data your app submitted to Health Connect.
